# I want to make a treemap structure. And I want to find a previouse tree

Tags: java, treemap

```
class Fran
{
  String name;
  int size;

  Fran(String name,int size)
  {  this.name=name;  this.size=size;  }

  String getName()
  {  return this.name;  }

  int getSize()
  {  return this.size;  }
}

class Node
{
    Fran fran;
    Node preNode;

    Node[] children=new Node[10];
    int childCount=0;
    Node child;

    /*  is there child?  */
    int isChild=0;

    Node(Fran fran)
    {
       this.fran=fran;
    }

    Node(Node preNode,Fran fran)
    {
      this.fran=fran;
      this.preNode=preNode;
    }

    void setChild(Node preNode,Node child)
    {
        this.preNode=preNode;
        this.child=child;
        this.children[childCount]=child;
        this.isChild=1;
        this.childCount++;
    }

    int getChildCount()
    {  return childCount;  }

    Node preNode()
    {  return this.preNode;  }

    String[] getName()
    {
        String[] t=new String[childCount];

        if(childCount==0)  {
            t[0]=this.fran.getName();
            return t;
        }
        else 
        {  
            for(int i=0;i<=childCount-1;i++)
            {
               t[i]=children[i].fran.getName();
            }
            return t;
        }
    }

    int[] getSize()
    {
      int[] t=new int[childCount];

      if(childCount==0)  {
        t[0]=this.fran.getSize();
        return t;
      }
      else 
      {
        for(int i=0;i<=childCount-1;i++)
        {
           t[i]=children[i].fran.getSize();
        }
      return t;
      }
    }

    String getN()
    {
       return this.fran.getName();
    }
}

void setup() 
{
  Fran aa=new Fran("apt",36);
  Fran bb=new Fran("bpt",26);
  Fran cc=new Fran("cpt",16);
  /*  Fran dd=new Fran("dpt",56);  */

  Node a=new Node(aa);
  Node b=new Node(bb);
  Node c=new Node(cc);

  a.setChild(a,b);
  a.setChild(a,c);

  print(a.getN());

  Node f=b.preNode();
  print(f.getN());
}
```

- I want to make a tree structure. And I want to return a previouse node.
- Node a->b, a->c . And I want to make b.preNode() -> Node a.
- But I have NullpointerException, how can I solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: This code is mislabelled.  It is not java, it looks like processing.  It's fairly close to java.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to clearly decide what you want to do.  You have not made that clear at all.  Is a the root, and b and c are its children? Or is a the root, b is its child, and c is the child of b?

You need an add method that will add a child to a node:

```
Node a = new Node (...);
Node b = new Node(...);
a.add(b); // this should hook them together
```

The add method should set the parent of b to a, and set the child of a to b.

In addition, note that you have some stylistic mistakes.  You should remove all your code setting variables and put it all together in the constructor.  It is very hard at the moment to see what happens when you create a node because you have the code spread over your whole class.

You should also consider removing the Fran class and put the data in Node.  Why have two classes?  It adds overhead, complexity, and does not seem to achieve anything.  That's just style, but it would clean up your code a lot.